# What am I doing wrong in my derivation of relativistic mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, acceleration

Recently I've been trying to derive some of relativity by myself, where $c=1$.

I believe I derived the correct worldline formula for an object under constant force in 1+1 dimensions, which is a hyperbola.

The differential equation I found was $a\left(t\right)=\frac{F}{m_{0}}\left(1-v\left(t\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

The solution I use for the position is $x\left(t\right)=\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{m^{2}}{F^{2}}}-\frac{m}{F}$.

Since I assume a constant force on the object, I thought I could get $m$, the relativistic mass by $m\left(t\right)=\frac{F}{a\left(t\right)}$.

Rearranging the differential equation from earlier, we get $\frac{m_{0}}{\left(1-v\left(t\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{F}{a\left(t\right)}$, so by the prior equality, $m\left(t\right)=\frac{m_{0}}{\left(1-v\left(t\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

If we assume that $v$ is an independent variable now, then $m=\frac{m_{0}}{\left(1-v^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Now after doing this I decided to look up what the actual expression was, and to my disappointment it was slightly off, being $m=\frac{m_{0}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}$, the power being $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{3}{2}$.

Personally I think there may be some problem with me assuming $m\left(t\right)=\frac{F}{a\left(t\right)}$, but I'm sure it could be different.

If there is a problem with it, why is it that the instantaneous mass is not just the force divided by the acceleration?

Or is it that my differential equation is wrong?

Or neither?

An answer with an explanation of my error, along with a derivation of the correct answer would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longitudinal and transverse mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580611/)

Comment: *Why is it that the instantaneous mass is not just the force divided by the acceleration?* See the section “What is the relativistic version of F = ma?” [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/mass.html).

Comment: BTW: Note that naturallyInconsistent’s link mentions that Einstein “later abandoned velocity dependent mass concepts.” Most physicists today consider relativistic mass an obsolete and unnecessary concept, and only use Lorentz-invariant mass.

Comment: @Ghoster What I seem to be getting is that the mass depends on which direction you apply the force, or am I misinterpreting this?

Although I don't understand how this applies to a particle in one spatial dimension.

Comment: You derived the “longitudinal mass” by working in 1D. I find any mass other than Lorentz-invariant mass incredibly distasteful, so I’m the wrong person to help you understand these different masses. I encourage you to follow Einstein and forget about the velocity-dependent ones.

Comment: @Ghoster so my longitudinal mass is correct?

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: In that case thank you, now I understand my mistake.

I was working in 1d, making it impossible for me to derive the other formula.

I will no longer be tearing my hair out.